# Output null value if column in not present

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Please excuse if this is a stupid question.

I wanted to select so many columns from different tables. So I have created a PHP script to do the same. The script is working properly. But some of the columns are not present in some of the tables.

So when I am running the script it is giving me an error "unknown column in field list" which is absolutely correct because that column is not present in that table.

Here comes my question: Is there any way to select the columns, if the column is not present it should give NULL value instead of the error "Unknown column in field list".

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If this sort of thing matters then your data is misstructured.

Comment: No, that is not possible and that is good. If your query does not make sense then it should return an error.

Comment: Cool. Thanks Guys for the quick reply. I will make changes in my query

Comment: As an alternative approach, you could find the columns on a table using: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM [table name]`

Comment: Surely the solution here is SELECT * FROM [table name] ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get away with using the `COALESCE()` mysql function.

`SELECT COALESCE(@maybe_col, null) AS norm_col FROM database;`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name='xxxx' and TABLE_SCHEMA='xxxx' and column_name='xxxx'
```

This will give the result if the column is present for that table or not